# The function of the に in 俺たちに足りない部分を埋めて

Tags: particle-に

「ああ。俺たちは確かに、歌でおまえには敵わなかった。......でも、メイドカフェや、他の出展物を用意してくれた生徒たちが、俺たち**に**足りない部分を埋めてくれたんだよ」

Hi. Could you explain the function of the に here? I previously thought it was because of てくれた until I’ve come across these examples.

1. 私に足りないものは、行動力と自信です。
2. 私たちに足りないものは何ですか？
3. あなたは私に足りないものを補う。

[https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&sxsrf=ALeKk00u7sjN7XpEyh0up_byAFi3gA1xgg%3A1598624042890&source=hp&ei=KhFJX8qANMqo5gLwm5yIBw&q=自分に足りないもの+英語&btnK=Google+搜索](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&sxsrf=ALeKk00u7sjN7XpEyh0up_byAFi3gA1xgg%3A1598624042890&source=hp&ei=KhFJX8qANMqo5gLwm5yIBw&q=%E8%87%AA%E5%88%86%E3%81%AB%E8%B6%B3%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE+%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E&btnK=Google+%E6%90%9C%E7%B4%A2)

So the use of に has nothing to do with てくれる.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

We say:

> A に B がある／いる *A has B*

on the same track:

> A に B が足りる *A has enough of B*

However, the ～に argument is less likely to show up in the affirmative sentence. So you see much more often in the form:

> A に B が足りない *A lacks B*

> 俺たちに足りない部分 *the part we lack / are short of / miss*